# Why a Play template expects Scala classes

Tags: scala, templates, playframework, playframework-2.0

The following template displays a PNG image by taking the image as a byte array and encoding it into Base64:

```
@(img: Array[Byte])
<img src="data:image/png;base64,@java.util.Base64.getEncoder.encodeToString(img)">
```

The template works for a Play project that uses Scala as its main language:

```
(lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala))
```

However, if a project uses Java as its main language:

```
(lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava))
```

The following error is seen when running the project:

```
[error] C:\Java\workspace\test\app\views\imgbase64.scala.html:2: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Array[java.lang.Byte]
[error]  required: Array[scala.Byte]
[error] <img src="data:image/png;base64,@java.util.Base64.getEncoder.encodeToString(img)">
[error]                                                                              ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

This is with Scala 2.11.4 and Play 2.3.6

Why does the template expect a Scala Byte instead of a Java Byte here, even though the Play project is configured to use Java?

Comment: What happens if you fully qualify the type by `@(img: Array[java.lang.Byte])` ?

Comment: Unfortunately nothing changes - the template already sees the parameter type as Array[java.lang.Byte], so fully qualifying it does not fix the problem.

Comment: I mean change the template. You mean you get compile error?

Comment: A silly question, but have you restarted your `sbt`? Have you tried `clean compile`?

Comment: Fully qualifying the parameter type does not change anything since the template already sees the correct type (`Array[java.lang.Byte]`), see where it says `[error]  found   : Array[java.lang.Byte]`. The problem is that it expects to find `Array[scala.Byte]` and I am trying to understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Twirl, the Play template compiler, is Scala based. It reads in the template and generates Scala source code. It doesn't matter that you enabled PlayJava, that doesn't change what the Twirl compiler generates.  I suggest you look at the source code under target/scala_2.X/twirl to see what Twirl generated and what the Scala compiler is attempting to compile. Twirl has likely interpreted `Byte` in your template as `scala.Byte` and output a fully qualified class name. You will need to be more specific in your template if you meant to use the java version of Byte.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I don't understand what you mean by being more specific in my template - fully qualifying the template parameter as `Array[java.lang.Byte]` has no effect as the template already sees it as this type (`[error]  found   : Array[java.lang.Byte]`)

Comment: I meant fully qualifying it as scala.Byte as in @(img: Array[scala.Byte]). The compiler is after expecting it to be that type.